# oracle handling no data from query

Tags: oracle, datetime, triggers

I am writing a trigger to check if an employee is allocated to two flights that overlap.

It would be something like:

```
select flight_id from flight 
where arrival_time > :new.departure_time
and departure_time < :new.arrival_time;

if flight_id is empty 
  [do nothing]
if flight_id exists
  [raise application error]
```

Can anyone help me out in how I would have to code the conditional logic there? This is my first time working with oracle (university coursework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT ... INTO` is your friend. It will raise an exception, you catch it, do nothing, otherwise and raise your own error.

```
select flight_id into v
from flight 
where arrival_time > :new.departure_time
and departure_time < :new.arrival_time;
raise_application_error(-20000, 'not good');
exception
when NO_DATA_FOUND
  then return 1
 when others
   then raise_application_error(-20011,'really good');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
   V_some_varible  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   Seclect 1 into v_some_varible from dual where 1 = 0;
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO errors (message) VALUES ('no data found');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors
      ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Note the 1 = 0 to force the no data found exception.  This example should work in any Oracle database with the exception of the insert into an errors table.